# How to replicate salesforce data to AWS S3/RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, salesforce, amazon-redshift

I am trying to build a data warehouse using RedShift in AWS. I want preprocess salesforce data my moving it to RDS or S3(use them as stage) before finally moving it to RedShift. I am trying to find out what are different ways on how I can replicate salesforce data in S3/RDS for this purpose. I have seen many third party tools which are able to do this.But I am looking for something which can be built in-house. I would like to use this data for dimensional modeling.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your question is to general and vague.. You should be more specific with why you are doing this and what you hope to accomplish. Also, I wouldnt really call Amazon RDS a data warehouse solution. Amazon Redshift is one of Amazons data warehouse offerings, but again we have no idea what you are trying to accomplish with this migrated data.

Comment: @JimP. I have updated my question.